# How to read a binary file in c? (video, images, or text)

Tags: c, fread

I am trying to copy a file from a specified library to the current directory. I can copy text files perfectly. Any other files become corrupt. The program detects a feof before it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
FILE *source;
FILE *destination;
int n;
int count = 0;
int written = 0;

int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    source = fopen("./library/rfc1350.txt", "r");

    if (source) {
        destination = fopen("rfc1350.txt", "w");

        while (!feof(source)) {
            n = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, source);
            count += n;
            printf("n = %d\n", n);
            fwrite(buffer, 1, n, destination);
        }
        printf("%d bytes read from library.\n", count);
    } else {
        printf("fail\n");
    }

    fclose(source);
    fclose(destination);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you on a Windows machine? Try adding "b" to the mode strings in the calls to `fopen`.

From man fopen(3):

> The  mode string can also include the letter 'b' either as a last character or as a character between the characters in any of the  two-character strings described above.  This is strictly for compatibility with C89 and has no effect; the 'b' is ignored on all POSIX conforming  systems,  including Linux.  (Other systems may treat text files and binary
>        files differently, and adding the 'b' may be a good idea if you do  I/O
>        to a binary file and expect that your program may be ported to non-Unix
>        environments.)

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the `"b"` option to `fopen`:

```
source = fopen("./library/rfc1350.txt", "rb");
...
destination = fopen("rfc1350.txt", "wb");
```

Without it, the file is opened in text (`"t"`) mode, and this results in translation of end-of-line characters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the files in binary format rather than text format. In your calls to `fopen`, use `"rb"` and `"wb"` rather than `"r"` and `"w"` respectively.