# Getting incorrect values from a bmp file

Tags: c, image, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a binary file in c? (video, images, or text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307057/how-to-read-a-binary-file-in-c-video-images-or-text)

I am trying to read the contents of a [bmp file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) using a C program. I am able to read the contents but the values read are on contradiction to what I expected. My code is :

---

```
FILE *fp=NULL;
fp=fopen("C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\Pictures\\nice.bmp","r");

if(fp!=NULL)
{
    printf("%c\n",fgetc(fp));
    printf("%c\n",fgetc(fp));

    printf("%c\n",fgetc(fp));
    printf("%c\n",fgetc(fp));
    printf("%c\n",fgetc(fp));
    printf("%c\n",fgetc(fp));
}

else
    printf("Error reading the file");
```

---

I am just reading byte by byte here, just for the sake of understanding. The first two bytes read `BM` which is correct. The next four byte reads `*t`. The value expected is 40. Please see the [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). Can someone please explain waht is happening and how can I get the value `40` if I need to perform some conversions.

Comment: And what are you getting...?  I'd half expect `BM(***` or something similar, if your expected value is correct.

Comment: Bytes 3 to 6 give the file size, "All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format (i.e. least-significant byte first)." Can you print out the values of bytes 3-6 as numbers and check whether that matches the file size?

Comment: Now from here, how do I get the file size. How do I marge the four bytes to get a single integral value ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is how you opened the file:

```
fp=fopen("C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\Pictures\\nice.bmp","r");
```

The "r" is for ASCII reading, you want to open it in binary:

```
fp=fopen("C:\\Users\\Saurabh\\Pictures\\nice.bmp","rb");
```

**EDIT:**
`fgetc()` returns an int, so I tried using an int to get the return value, also you want to see the results in hex, so let's use a hex output format:

```
FILE *readf;
int i;
unsigned int size = 0;

//Open file
readf = fopen("blackbuck.bmp", "rb");

i = fgetc(readf);
printf("%#x\n",i);   // 0x42
i = fgetc(readf);
printf("%#x\n",i);   // 0x4D
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    size |= fgetc(readf) << (i*8); // 0xC0036
```

This update gives the first two values as 0x42 0x4D, then concatinates the next 3 bytes giving the size of the bitmap (0xC0036 = 786486 bytes)

I used this image for the test: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/bmp/blackbuck.bmp

You can see the result has the correct byte code for a bmp header `0x42 0x4d`
`the header field used to identify the BMP & DIB file is 0x42 0x4D in hexadecimal, same as BM in ASCII`

Comment: This typically only matters if there's a char typically found in line endings (`\n`, `\r`) in the input.  I wouldn't expect it to mangle input this early.

Comment: Even with "rb", i get the same output..

Comment: @CSSS - Give the code/pic combo I just posted a try and let me know if it's still not working for you.

Comment: @Mike: I tried your code and it prints well in hexadecimal. But how do i print it in decimal ?

Comment: @CSSS - Just change the format specifier `printf("%d\n",i);`. I just figured since the page you're looking at for format is reporting values in hex, that would be easier on you.

Comment: @Mike: I get 42 116 7 0 in bytes 3 to 6. Can you please explain as to how to get one integer value from these four bytes !!

Comment: @CSSS - I updated the code to show you how. It's read the bytes from the stream and bitwise OR (|) them together, after each read you have to shift by a multiple of 8 (<<)

Answer (score 1):

While i agree with Mike that you should be reading this file in binary mode, it shouldn't be causing you problems just yet.  It will, eventually, but the first 6 chars should not break unless any byte of the size contains a 10 or 13.

In order to read an int, you could do something like

```
int result;
fread(fp, sizeof (int), 1, &result);
```

but be aware that this is not portable.  (It assumes 32-bit ints and native byte order, at the least.  BMPs, due to their origin, are little-endian...and the size would be all wacky if you just read it in all at once on a big-endian machine.)

Another way:

```
unsigned long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
     result |= (unsigned long) fgetc(fp) << (i * 8);
}
```

This should at least always read the right number of bytes and account for endianness.  And `unsigned long` is long enough to hold any 32-bit number, whereas `int` (even unsigned) is not guaranteed to be.