# ERROR While read File C

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I'm getting an error with this code.  The output looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q41k.png)

Why is the output half normal?

I want the output to be:

> 2 ppa 90 90 98 89 49 83.20 B
>   junior 90 90 90 90 90 90.00 A

Here is my code:

```
void class_result(){
     system("cls");
     fptr=fopen("stdnin.txt","r");
     if(fptr==NULL)
     {
       printf("ERROR!!! FILE COULD NOT BE OPEN\n\n\n Go To Entry Menu to create File");
       printf("\n\n\n Program is closing ....");
       getch();
       exit(0);
     }

      printf("\n\n\t\tALL STUDENTS RESULT \n\n");
      printf("====================================================\n");
      printf("R.No.  Name       P   C   M   E   CS  %age   Grade\n");
      printf("====================================================\n");
//  while(fscanf(fptr,"%d %s %d %d %d %d %d %.2f %c",&st.rollno,st.name,&st.p_marks,&st.c_marks,&st.m_marks,&st.e_marks,&st.cs_marks,&st.per,st.grade)!=EOF){


 while(fread(&st,sizeof(st),1,fptr))
   {
       printf("%-6d %-10s %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3d %-3.2f %-2c\n",st.rollno,st.name,st.p_marks,st.c_marks,st.m_marks,st.e_marks,st.cs_marks,st.per,st.grade);
     }
//      while(fread(&st,sizeof(st),1,fptr))
//        printf ("%d %s \n",st.rollno, st.name);
 fclose(fptr);
     getch();
}
```

Comment: are you using windows? then you should open your file in binary mode `fptr=fopen("stdnin.txt","rb");` because else it converts linefeeds to CR+LF and corrupts the output. note: I'm sure you're using windows: cls & getch are dead giveaway.

Comment: What is 'st'?  Data is more important than code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a binary file in c? (video, images, or text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307057/how-to-read-a-binary-file-in-c-video-images-or-text)

Comment: I'm not using binary .. i have txt data to read

Comment: st is from struct data

Comment: full code https://pastebin.com/0tsyNx6W

Comment: You are writing text but reading as if it's memory. Ask your instructor about reading text files raw and then converting strings to the in-memory values. atoi() is the function you'll use, or similar types. This is not a problem with the code, but a fundamental understanding behind what's going on.

Comment: I haven't instructor yet ,,,

Comment: maybe you can give me a sugest ..

Comment: `fread` is used to read binary data. `fgets`, `getchar`, `fscanf`, etc are used to read text. (note the `scanf` family of functions is full of traps for the unwary new C programmer). Each function has a return. ***validate*** all input by checking the return of whatever function you use. Suggest starting with `fgets` and do not use `atoi` for string to integer conversions -- it provides ZERO error checking, use `strtol` instead. Always consult the *man page* for any function you use (even after you think you know it cold)

Comment: i've tried using fscanf but still error ... same ... while(fscanf(fptr,"%d %s %d %d %d %d %d %.2f %c",&st.rollno,st.name,&st.p_marks,&st.c_marks,&st.m_marks,&st.e_marks,&st.cs_marks,&st.per,st.grade)!=EOF){

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0tsyNx6W

Comment: In `printf("R.No.  Name       P   C   M   E   CS  %age   Grade\n");` the `%` is a typo or do you want to print that symbol?

Comment: @Bob__ yeah typo .. the important is i want  data below is showing well .. ;D

Comment: Could you please edit your question adding some lines of the input file?

Comment: here  
pastebin.com/0tsyNx6W

Comment: @AgrowGrowan what will be most helpful for allowing me to help you is to post any existing `"stdnin.txt"` file that you are required to start with (meaning if it already has data you are supposed to read and then add to), if you are creating it from scratch, let me know that too.

Comment: Don't include an image for pure text output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make up your mind if you want to read/write the file in text mode or in binary mode. You cannot open the file in text mode and write in binary mode, or vice versa.

To read in binary mode, open the file as binary (use "rb" instead of "r"), use `fread` and `fwrite`. If your file already contains text data then you must delete that file and start with a new one.

```
fptr = fopen("stdnin.txt", "ab+");
fwrite(&st,sizeof(st),1,fptr);
fclose(fptr);
...

fptr = fopen("stdnin.txt", "rb");
while(fread(&st, sizeof(st), 1, fptr))
    printf...;
```

To read/write in text mode, open the file in text mode, use `fscanf(fptr, ...)` and `fprintf(fptr, ...)`. Again, if your file contains binary data then you must delete the file start with a new file for text input.

To read text input from console you can use `scanf`, not `gets`